# Accessing Function on MovieClip from Document Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs5.5, document-class

> **[NOTE: Right off the bat, I already know the popular theory about "no code on MovieClips," so please don't reply with that (or
>   downvote because of it). Every project is different. I just need the answer.]**

I have a project in Adobe Flash CS5.5, Adobe AIR 3, and ActionScript 3.

I need to **call a function on the main timeline of the project** that the document class is linked to **from inside the document class**. For the sake of example, let's call this function "Ring()".

How do I call this function, "Ring()" from inside my document class?

Comment: Wont you be getting an addframescript error if you try to write code on timeline as well as have a document class linked?

Comment: No. I've been pulling it off without the slightest hitch since December, when I started my project. I use a combination of timeline code, document class code, and custom classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you seem to be using some oldskool ninja techniques, I would suggest that you should keep it simple and straightforward.

Say you have some functions on the main timeline:

```
function Ring1():String
{
    return "Ring1() called!";
}
var Ring2:Function = function () : String
{
    return "Ring2() called!";
};
```

The scenario for a document class of the said timeline would be like this:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
    import flash.utils.describeType;

    public class Test extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function Test() 
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
        }
        private function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(getQualifiedClassName(this)+".onMouseDown()");
            try {
                var ring1:Function = this["Ring1"] as Function;
                var ring2:Function = this["Ring2"] as Function;
            } catch (error:Error) {         
                // ignore
            }
            if (ring1 != null) {
                trace("\t", "Ring1", "=", ring1);
                trace("\t", ring1());
            } else {
                trace("\t", "Ring1() function not found in "+this+"!");
            }           
            if (ring2 != null) {
                trace("\t", "Ring2", "=", ring2);
                trace("\t", ring2());
            } else {
                trace("\t", "Ring2() function not found in "+this+"!");
            }

            // for your interest:
            var doc:XML = describeType(this);
            var ring1Node:XML = doc.descendants("method").(@name == "Ring1")[0];
            var ring2Node:XML = doc.descendants("variable").(@name == "Ring2")[0];
            trace("declaration of Ring1:", ring1Node.toXMLString());
            trace("declaration of Ring2:", ring2Node.toXMLString());
            // so, you may probably make use of reflection
            // unless you need to reference dynamic members on the main timeline
        }   
    }
}
```

See comments in the code above.

Comment: I ended up finding another method on my own, but since this is closer to what I asked for, I'll accept it to get this off of the Unanswered Questions list. Sorry for the delay, and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put the function you want to call in your document class, and dispatch a custom event (or any event, if the code is readable) from the timeline of the object and listen for that event on your document class.

So the code breakdown would look like this:

On some frame of the timeline in your document (should work on *any* object):

```
var customEvent:Event = new Event(Event.COMPLETE);
this.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

In your document class:

```
public function DocumentClass()
{
    // get the reference to the object
    lolcats.objectThatDispatchesEvent.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _customHandler);
}

protected function _customHandler(event:Event):void
{
    // FUNCTION NAMES SHOULD START WITH LOWERCASE! ^_^
    Ring();
}
```

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html

Basically you register any string that defines your event, `Event.COMPLETE` evaluates to `"complete"`, you can just register whatever you want, like:

```
var custEvent = new Event("anyCustomString");
this.dispatchEvent(custEvent);

// catch it with
addEventListener("anyCustomString", _handler);
```

Comment: Okay, not quite sure I'm following you. How does the event listener know to listen for customEvent?

Comment: I updated my answer, to better explain that, I'm kinda sorry, I haven't used something more "custom" as my example.

Comment: What inspires your naming of members..?

Comment: MartyWallace, LOL, I was wondering the same thing! Joncys, I still don't get it, but then its 11:48 PM here. I'll try it out and get back to you in the morning ^^

Comment: @JasonMc92 You explicitly tell the scope on which to listen to. So if you listen to some event (be it `Event.COMPLETE`) on only your object foo by adding an event listener as such: `foo.addEventListener`, the code in your handler function gets called every time that _particular_ object dispatches an `Event.COMPLETE` event. If you however listen for events on stage (i.e. `this.stage.addEventListener`, then you can have multiple objects dispatch events and by event propagation they'll end up on stage, so your event handler kinda behaves as a catch all in that case.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Bear in mind, event bubbling (propagation) is set to false by default, so you need to enable that in the `Event` constructor` — `new Event("randomEventNameHamburgers", true /*this is the bubbles flag*/);`

Comment: @joncys That just made my day; have a `+1`.

Comment: @MartyWallace I'm a sucker, when it comes to lame _brogrammer_ slash _meme_ jokes in code markup. Seeing something named `potato` instead of `foo` or `bar` adds the excitement back to programming (much like the old good times of _ALGOL68_, which I sadly couldn't experience).

Comment: @JasonMc92 — This is pretty basic stuff, and if you don't get this, the best thing for you to do, would be to present a clear use case scenario of what you want to do, in a complete new question — maybe someone will come up with a clear "hands on" solution, not just abstract coding methodology. If you lack knowledge of the platform itself, on the other hand, go out and check some tutorials on event handling, and basic actionscript programming in general. It's a pretty cool and straight-forward language, you'll catch it in no time.

Comment: Okay, so if I'm reading this right, that string in your custEvent identifies my custom event. dispatchEvent(custEvent) causes it to happen. And I just add the eventlistener to the document class. Okay, useful, but not quite what I was looking for ^^;

Comment: I specifically need to call the function Ring();, which is on the TIMELINE, FROM the DOCUMENT CLASS, not the other way around. Perhaps this works in reverse?

Comment: Here's an analogy for ya — You want to go out into the forest and find John and see what he has to report. I suggest you abandon this approach and instead tell John to come to your house and fill in a paper. Moreover, your need to call the function from the timeline is probably bad design, I was trying to suggest a different approach, hope you'll find what you're looking for in that another answer. Cheers.

Comment: Well, difference of design opinion, I suppose, but a useful answer all the same. It may come in handy one of these days (upvote). Thanks for the help.